# Introductory Price not showing In Android Google Billing SDK ( In India )

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I am not able to find a way to show introductory price in android-google-billing-pop-up,

**My Problem :**

```
as you can see that introductory price are not showing even for new user also.
```

[image]

**what I have explored :**

- [Android Play Billing Library: get product introductory price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033802/android-play-billing-library-get-product-introductory-price?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Android Purchase subscription and introductory price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035514/android-purchase-subscription-and-introductory-price)

and this document,

[image]

So if I go with the above google-doc then I can get introductory price

[image]

and passed modified json with replacing price with intro price still not working

[image]

but not able to find a way to display introductory price in SDK.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm facing the same problem, the payment sheet that pops up on Buy subscription shows the original price instead of the introductory price. @tushar-pandey

Comment: Hi Vinay this is google's issue I have posted this issue to google-developer-support but didn't got any response, but you can try for creating new item & buy it with creating new test user only this is given in all support pages.

Comment: Yea, I guess the problem is, in India Google is actually freezing auto renewing subscription and free trials. Check this article https://www.engadget.com/google-play-store-india-halts-auto-renewing-subscriptions-162021215.html

I'm working on a React-Native project and when I sent the build to a user outside India to check the introductory offer, there it is actually showing the introductory offer in the payment sheet that pop ups. So this may be the reason.

Comment: Hi, @TusharPandey can you please attach the link to your issue tracker so that anyone seeing this and having the same issue can specify the same in the issue tracker as well?

Comment: yes I think in India introductory price is not working, in US it is showing.

Comment: @VinayN got the email from google regarding it.

Comment: @Kartik got the email from google regarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this email from google, so In **India Introductory Price will not show**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should normally work alone.

If you're not seeing the introductory price, it may be because you've already benefited from this offer in the past.

Try creating a new subscription in the Google Play Console, with an introductory price. Then buy it in your app: the promotional offer should be displayed.

Comment: hi , I haven't benefited any offer , because I am still getting introductory price in response and I have also checked all my previous receipt for checking consuming introductory price.

Comment: I'm not sure of what I'm going to say, but it's not because you have an "introductory_price" in the response of `querySkuDetailsAsync` that your can benefit from this offer: it just means that IF your user hasn't benefited from it THEN the intro pricing will be available. And if you're saying this "introductory price" is present in your previous receipt, it does mean you've already benefited from it (as explained here, under `introductoryPriceInfo`: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions). If I were you, I would create a new sub, just in case.